# Database error handling with Sequelize when column doesn't exist?

Tags: express, sequelize.js

I'm trying to handle different errors that might show up when inserting into a MYSQL database.

Using Sequelize with express.

My foo.js model file looks like this:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, type) => {
  return sequelize.define('event', {
    id: {
      type: type.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    name: {
      type: type.STRING,
      }
  },{
    freezeTableName: true,
    rejectOnEmpty: true,
  })
}
```

and my route file (or whatever you wanna call it), looks like this.

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const fooModel = require('../../models/Foo')
const router = require('express').Router();
const auth = require('../auth');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const sequelize = new Sequelize('username', 'password', 'db', {
      host: 'localhost',
      dialect: 'mysql'
})

const Foo = fooModel(sequelize, Sequelize);
router.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '100mb'}));
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: '100mb', parameterLimit: 1000000 }));


sequelize.sync({force: true})
.then(() => {
      console.log('Worked');
});

router.post('/', (req,res,next) => {
      if(Object.keys(req.body).length > 0){ 
            return Foo.create({
                  Name: req.body.Name
            }).then((result) => {
                  if(result){
                        return res.status(200).json(result);
                  }else{
                        return res.status(400).json({'error': 'Could not create record.'});
                  }
            }).catch(Sequelize.DatabaseError, function(err){
                return res.status(400).json(err);
            }).catch(function(err){
                res.send(err);
            })
      }else{
            return res.status(400).json({'error': 'error'});
      }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Whenever I try to post to the route with something like:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "foo": "bar"
}
```

Sequelize accepts the body and puts "test" in the ”name” column, and ignores the "foo" column, because the "foo" column does not exist. Meaning, all I get back once it's posted is:

```
{"id": "123",
createdAt: 2020-01-23 13:337:00
updatedAt: 2020-01-23 13:337:00
}
```

And not an error as I expect.

What Im trying to do, is catch that error (that I today ain't recieving) whenever I try to post to a column that doens't exist, basically replicate a normal MYSQL error behaviour.

Could someone point me in the right direction on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, it would be better to avoid this particular problem by validating the fields on the client side.

But, you can trap such a condition in js.  You'll not get a DB exception because Sequelize isn't sending your unrecognized attributes to the database.

```
if (!Foo.attributes.hasOwnProperty('foo')) { 
   // some error handing here, for invalid field.
}
```

You could write a utility function to iterate through the attributes of `req.body` and send an appropriate error to the response.

FWIW, you'll find that `Name` is also invalid, because your model specifies(lower case) `name`

hth